# the nchannel() returns always 1 even in the case of color video image

Tags: opencv

I'm coding an opencv 2.1 program with visual c++ 2008 express. I want to get each pixel color data of each pixel and modify them by pixel.

I understand that the code "frmSource.channels();" returns the color channels of the mat frmSource, but it always returns 1 even if it is absolutely color video image, not 3 or 4.

Am I wrong?

If I'm wrong, please guide me how to get the each color component data of each pixel.

Also, the total frame count by "get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)" is much larger than the frame count I expected, so I divide the "get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) by get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS Frame rate.") and I can get the result as I expected.

I understand that the frame is like a cut of a movie, and 30 frames per sec. Is that right?

My coding is as follows:

```
void fEditMain()
{

VideoCapture vdoCap("C:/Users/Public/Videos/Sample Videos/WildlifeTest.wmv");

// this video file is provided in window7

if( !vdoCap.isOpened() ) 

{

    printf("failed to open!\n");

    return;

}

Mat frmSource;

vdoCap >> frmSource; 

if(! frmSource.data) return;


VideoWriter vdoRec(vRecFIleName, CV_FOURCC('W','M','V','1'), 30, frmSource.size(), true);

namedWindow("video",1);

// record video

int  vFrmCntNo=1;
for(;;)
{
    int vDepth = frmSource.depth();

    vChannel = frmSource.channels(); 

    // here! vChannel is always 1, i expect 3 or 4 because it is color image

    imshow("video", frmSource);// frmSource Show

    vdoRec << frmSource; 

    vdoCap >> frmSource;

    if(! frmSource.data) 

    return;
}        
return;
}
```

Comment: What's the type of `vChannel` ?

Comment: OpenCV is on version 2.3.1! I strongly suggest you update your version.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will answer your question but if you use IplImage it will  be very easy to get the correct number of channels as well as manipulate the image. Try using:

```
IplImage *frm = cvQueryFrame(cap);
int numOfChannels = channelfrm->nChannels;
```

A video is composed of frames and you can know how many frames pass in a second by using get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS). If you divide the frame count by the FPS you'll get the number of seconds for the clip.